# Continuity in weak star topology

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

If $K$ is $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$, consider $$\varphi : \ell^{1}(\mathbb N) \to K$$ that is defined by $(a_{j})\mapsto \varphi((a_{j})):=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_{j}.$

I want to prove that $\varphi$ is continuous in norm but not with respect to the weak* topology of $\ell^{1}=(c_{0})'$. Continuity in norm is easy to see because the sequences is in $\ell^{1}$ so if the series converges absolutely then the series converges and this linear function is norm bounded, but I don't have clear the definition of continuity with regards to the weak topology. How can I proceed?

Comment: Is $K$ the underlying field, which is either $\mathbb C$ or $\mathbb R$? What is the definition of continuity for a general topological space?

Comment: yeah, $K$ is the field. The definition of continuity for a general topological space is that the inverse image of open in $K$ is open in $l^{1}$

Answer (score 4):

Consider the kronecker-delta sequence $(\delta^n):=((\delta_i^n)_{i\in\mathbb N})_{n\in\mathbb N}\subset \ell^1$, where $\delta_n^n=1$ and $\delta_i^n=0$ if $i\neq n$. Then for every $c=(c_i)\in c_0$ we know that $\delta^n(c)=c_n\to 0$, meaning that $\delta^n$ converges to $0$ in the weak* topology (it is crucial that you understand why). However,
$$\varphi(\delta^n)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty\delta_i^n=1\neq 0=\varphi(0).$$
Thus $\varphi$ is not sequentially continuous, so definitely not continuous (in $\ell^1(\mathbb N)$ these are, in fact, [equivalent](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/284276/sequential-continuity-in-dual-spaces-of-separable-banach-spaces)) .

Comment: As $\ell^1$ is separable, the weak star topology on the unit ball is metrizable. Hence sequential continuity and continuity coincide.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc indeed, but in any topological space continuity always implies sequential continuity, so this point does not affect the validity of the argument in any way.

Comment: Validity is not affected, but the last sentence in your answer is redundant.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc You are, of course, correct mathematically. The proof that a metrisable unit ball is enough to guarantee the equivalence of sequential continuity and continuity for linear maps is not totally trivia though, and so it is likely that students in a first FA course do not know it. Thus I thought it best to avoid any implication that this fact is important for the argument.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Although having said that, I guess it is always good to increase students' knowledge, so I have included a link to the proof of this fact now

Comment: I would agree if the argument went the other way around: that you need to prove continuity, hence sequential continuity sufficed. In this case the argument looks like: the number is less than $-10$ let alone negative. But that is the matter of taste.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Indeed, I can see why you might find the wording a bit jarring. I have thus changed the wording to hopefully make the answer tasteful to more people. Thank you for the fruitful discussion.